# How to add piecewise functions with different domains?

Tags: functions

I have two piecewise functions:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 2 \qquad x > 2 \\
3 \qquad x <2
\end{cases}
$$
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} -2 \qquad x \ge 2 \\
2 \qquad x <2
\end{cases}
$$

I need to calculate $g(x) - f(x)$ but I don't understand what happens at $x = 2$ as only $g(x)$ is defined there.

Comment: The domain of the difference of two functions is the intersection of the domains. Thus, $x=2$ gets excluded.

Comment: @quasi so $g(x) - f(x)$ is undefined at $x = 2$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. After all, how would you do a subtraction of "undefined" minus a number?

Comment: @quasi will the same logic hold for other arithmetic operations on the functions?

Comment: Yes, definitely. So multiplication would have the same issue. For division of two functions, the new domain would be the subset of the intersection of the domains for which the denominator is nonzero.

Comment: @quasi what about the composition of $f(g(x))$?

Comment: $g(x)$ needs to be defined otherwise $f$ can't accept the input. But $g(x)$ would also need to be in the domain of $f$. Thus, the new domain is the set of $x$ values in the domain of $g$ such that $g(x)$ is an element of the domain of $f$.

Comment: so it's also impossible because the domain of $f(x)$ is only a subset of the domain of $g(x)$?

Comment: No, think that through. Better yet, experiment. What is $f(g(4))\,?$ What is $f(g(-13))\,?$

Comment: I think that for any $x \ge 2$, $f(g(x)) = 3$ but for any $x < 2$ the result is undefined.

Comment: Yes, very good. So $f(g(x)) = 3,\; x \ge 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it into cases.

For $x<2,$ $f(x)=3$ and $g(x)=2$ so $g(x)-f(x)=-1$ for $x<2.$

At $x=2$ $f(x)$ doesn't exist so $g(x)-f(x)$ is undefined here.

For $x>2$ it's just $-2-2=-4.$

Comment: Needs a few edits. For $x < 2, g(x) - f(x) = ?$ Also, for the case $x=2$, you need some dollar signs.

Comment: dangit fixed lol